# Showing differences between two sets of geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

Can QGIS show the differences between two sets of polygons?

A map is filled completely with adjacent object geometries, so there are no gaps or overlaps. An object could be a street or a house.

You can change the map by providing a set of changes of object geometries (in an XML file). After applying the changes, the map should not contain holes/gaps or overlaps.

To make a change to an object's geometry on the map, first, the "current" geometry (that is on the map) is given, then the change in the geometry as a "new" geometry.

There are 3 types of changes:

1. A change consists of a new object with only a "new" geometry;
2. A change has a only "current" geometry and no "new" geometry, so indicating is will be removed.
3. A change has a "current" geometry and a (changed) "new" geometry.

Example: an error is introduced while splitting 1 object into 2 parts.

- Object 1: replace 'current' 4x3 meter geometry with a 'new' 2x3 meter geometry;
- Ojbect 2: a 'new' object geometry is 1x3 meter geometry.

This set of changes introduces a hole in the map of 1x3 meter. See in this picture:
[image]

**Question**: How to show any gaps and overlaps of the polygons of the "current" and "new" situation in a .gml file using QGIS?

**In other words**: let Qgis show the differences between the current set of polygons and the new set of polygons.

**Sample file**

I cannot share original files. Having not many means at this spot, I still tried to create a sample file. I could not validate it in qgis at this location.

[Sample change file](https://gist.github.com/johan974/cf6af2a5e5a0b24b88661c795e33fefd)

This set of 3 changes will split object 123 in half. Object 124 will replace only a small part of the original 123 geometry. Object 125 will overlap partly with the new geometry of object 123.

So this change would introduce 2 errors: there will be a gap between 125 and 124. Object 125 also overlaps with the new geometry of object 123.

**Another simplified example file.**

The structure of a simplified change file is:

[Sample file structure](https://gist.github.com/johan974/fe3df7643957975eabf1a30531332321)

**Update: Some ideas**

Because the map has no overlaps or gaps we know the current geometries are correct. A good baseline. To find any gaps introduced by the new geometries, could we make a union of all current objects and substract all new geometries? Additionally, could we make a union of the new geometries and subtract the current geometries? Ok, we should add the intersections between new geometries as errors.

**Background info:**

Because the existing huge map doesn't have holes/overlaps, I only want QGIS to check 1 set of changes at any time.

The simplified objects have a GML geometry and two attributes: id + current/new indication.

There is a process validating any sets of changes. On successful validation, the set of changes is applied to the map. On validation errors, the error messages are specified.

To improve the analysis of errors, I would like to import one set of changes to qgis, so qgis will show any errors visually. So, in the above example, QGIS will mark the hole on the map. The geographic data is stored in GML format.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You have an xml file saved on your hard drive, it causes errors and you just want to find holes and intersections in this file? If so, then I need to look at the content of your xml. How is your geographic data stored?

Comment: The geographic data is in gml format. The original file is eg in citigml format. I preprocess the file, export it so it contains in essence a very simple format with per object being the id, the gml, the current/new indication and the termination date. I can drag the file into a new Qgis layer and I can see the geometries. I can categorize on current/new and I see all current or new geometries.

Comment: It seems to me that you have complicated your question, a lot of unnecessary details, people do not understand your need. Your question should look something like this: `How to find gaps and overlaps between polygons in a .gml file using QGIS?` An example of your file and your wish for gaps and overlaps to be displayed graphically. Sorry for the advice, but I recommend that you redo your question in this way, then you will probably get several answers on how to do this, provide information about your file and a screen shot with objects.

Comment: Rethinking the question again I simplified it. Thanks for challenging the question. See eg the title and rephrasing the question. And simplified the data!

Comment: The current and new geometries are both stored in the same GML file? It would likely help to include a sample of your data to give a clearer picture of what you are working with. If your data are sensitive you could make a small mock sample of 2 or 3 situations.

Comment: Added a simplified input file.

Comment: Without having any means at this location, I still tried to devise a sample file. See the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a style for displaying gaps and intersections. It uses a QGIS expression to find two geometries that have the same "id" field value and "type" field value = 'new'. The intersection or gap between these two geometries is then obtained as a new geometry that is displayed on the map.
[image]

You can **download the [style](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0N3tle1aTP2L45ouAOMxFxEYAMUn3Us/view?usp=drive_link) and the [gml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WCEdPLHKF3Nq2Ocb-xDgcUD3A1Is8Qw7/view?usp=drive_link)** I created from google drive. Open the GML file in QGIS and apply a style to it.

### **Style Explanation**

**1. Rule for displaying gaps**

First we combine two geometries that have the same "id" field value and "type" field value = 'new' using the `combine` function, then we subtract this combined geometry from the same combined geometry wrapped in `convex_hull`.

```
with_variable('combine_geom', 
combine(geometry(get_feature(@layer, map('id', attribute('id'),'type','new'))), $geometry),
difference(convex_hull(@combine_geom), @combine_geom))
```

[image]

**2. Rule for displaying intersections**

Here we get the feature geometry that has the same "id" field value as the current feature and "type" field value = 'new'. Then we get the `intersection` of the geometries of these two features, it will be displayed on the map. Unfortunately, I myself do not understand how the `overlaps` function works here. But without it, the result is not correct.

```
with_variable('new_geom_2', 
geometry(get_feature(@layer, map('id', attribute('id'),'type','new'))),
if (overlaps(@new_geom_2, $geometry),
intersection(@new_geom_2, $geometry),
null))
```

[image]

**3. Turn on symbol levels**

We turn on the display levels for the rules so that gaps and intersections are not hidden by ordinary objects. We set our gaps and intersections to a value greater than the rest of the objects so that the gaps and intersections are on top.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, helping me to get the question improved and this answer.

Comment: Thank you again. I studied your data.  Please check the rules for the 3 change types. One change consists of a current (or old situation) and a new geometry. An unique object (with 1 I'd) can't have more than one 'new' situation. See the given example that displays a gap. An overlap example would be to add a third (new) object that is larger than the missing 1x3 part.

Comment: What do you mean by "current (or old situation)"? I don't understand what "situation" means in this context?

Comment: Much appreciated for helping! We know the map is at any point in time valid. It contains many objects (with their geometries). To change 1 object of the map, you first specify the current geometry of the object. To replace that geometry we then specify the geometry as the NEW geometry. Please note in the question the "some ideas" paragraph.

Comment: Let's look at the gap rule first. Judging by your picture, you are replacing the old object with two new objects, there is a gap between the two new objects that needs to be displayed on the map, do I understand correctly? Do the two new objects have the same id? Where does my rule for gaps not match your conditions?

Comment: Example 1: Object id1 (already on the map) had a current geometry of 4x3. That same object id1 is proposed to change with a new geometry of 2x3. A new object id2 has a new geometry of 1x3. When these were the only changes applied to the map, a gap of 1x3 exists. Example 2: as above and additionally as a third object id3 that exactly fits the 1x3 gap geometry. That would leave the map without a gap. Example 3 based on example 1. Suppose id3 is a new object with a new geometry 2x3. It overlaps the new id1 geometry partly, that would leave the end result map with an overlap.

Comment: Let's deal with gaps first. That is, you want to find a gap between the old and new objects, they are not related in any way by id. Then I don’t understand why I need to know all these examples at all, if the objects between which you want to find a gap are not connected in any way? Why do I need to know that one object was inserted first, that a second object was inserted later? And a gap formed between them, because it is so obvious... Why is this information important for finding gaps between objects?

Comment: So far, I see that you just have a set of objects between which you want to find gaps and intersections, right? Some of these objects are new, but why does it matter?

Comment: Regarding the "some ideas" paragraph, I can tell you that yes we can. We can union and subtract any geometries. This can be done with the Processing Toolbox, pyqgis scripts, or QGIS expressions and styles like in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148257/discussion-between-tm1701-and-vsevolod-tsukanov).